# How to know that a celery task is complete and retrieve the result of the task?

Tags: python, celery

I've not chained tasks in Celery.

It is a straightforward API call that gets me a particular number, which I need to show in another Django view.

Going by this question before:

[celery - call function on task done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576160/celery-call-function-on-task-done)

I've decided to do a POST once my task returns some value, so that the Django view can be updated. The problem here is what happens if the task fails? It is difficult to take care of various errors that can occur due to more than one reasons and send back POST requests for them.

Is there any other way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

Option #1:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#module-celery.result

Check `result.status` for not being `FAILURE`.

Option #2:

Override `on_success` in your task class and do a POST request there.

Comment: Can you give me an example as to how I can override on_success?